# How to apply EDIT and Cancel features using inline row vue Grid

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, grid, vue-component

I am trying to make an edit and cancel/undo function on my inline-grid row.

This is what I have tied and I cannot see how to make it functional.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- ..iterate.. -->
<span v-if="!row.isEditable" v-html="row.column"></span>
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  v-model="row.column" //object property set
  v-if="row.isEditable"
/>
<button class="btn cancel" v-show="row.isEditable" v-on:click="undoRow(index)"></button>
<button class="btn edit" v-show="!row.isEditable" v-on:click="editRow(index)"></button>
```

**JS Methods:**

```
//..

editRow: function (index) {
  this.data[index].isEditable = true;
},
undoRow: function (index) {
  this.data[index].isEditable = false;                
}
```

Comment: What is `row.column`? And why do you use v-html? I cannot see why you would want to do that when you also use the same key as the value of the input. You cannot have HTML as value to an input. If  `row.column` is a value like `"Hello world"` you would rather want to use either v-text or just mustache brackets in the span.

Comment: Also, can you add some aditional information on what exactly is not working? If it is only the undoRow, this is because you have the an undefined variable `dataIndex`. Did you mean to write `index` as the parameter?